# Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument.SerializeAsV2 Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, autorest

I am upgrading my API from .netcore 2.1 to 3.1

The API uses `SwagerUI` and `Autorest` to generate the client.

From  [this question about Autorest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595335/autorest-error-swagger-json-is-not-a-valid-openapi-2-0-definition-expected) I found out that I need to use:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
});
```

However, the UI gives:

```
Fetch error
Internal Server Error v1/swagger.json
```

The JSON is:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 500,
  "ErrorMessage": "Internal server error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. nStack:
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument.WriteHostInfoV2(IOpenApiWriter writer, IList`1 servers)
    at Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument.SerializeAsV2(IOpenApiWriter writer)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.RespondWithSwaggerJson(HttpResponse response, OpenApiDocument swagger)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
  "SystemMessage": "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."
}
```

[Update]

I found mention of it [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1509):

```
c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
{
    swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{pathPrefix}" } };
});
```

Now the JSON shows:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 500,
  "ErrorMessage": "Internal server error: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified. Stack:
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument.WriteHostInfoV2(IOpenApiWriter writer, IList`1 servers)
    at Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiDocument.SerializeAsV2(IOpenApiWriter writer)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.RespondWithSwaggerJson(HttpResponse response, OpenApiDocument swagger)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
  "SystemMessage": "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified."
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1509

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked

```
        var basePath = "/v1";
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
            {
                swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{basePath}" } };
            });

        });
```

Comment: I since learned I could use v3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820577/note-autorest-core-version-selected-from-configuration-2-0-4413-when-i-have-i