# Note: AutoRest core version selected from configuration: ~2.0.4413 when I have installed 3.06187

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autorest, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have installed autorest 3.0.3187 on node v12.16.1
and I ran

```
autorest --reset
```

to remove old versions

However when I run

```
autorest --input-file=https://myapplication/mydocs/v1/swagger.json --output-folder=generated --csharp --namespace=MyNameSpace
```

I get the following output

```
NOTE: AutoRest core version selected from configuration: ~2.0.4413.
Loading AutoRest core      
'C:\Users\kirst\.autorest\@microsoft.azure_autorest- 
core@2.0.4417\node_modules\@microsoft.azure\autorest-core\dist' (2.0.4417)
Loading AutoRest extension '@microsoft.azure/autorest.csharp' (~2.3.79- 
>2.3.84)
Loading AutoRest extension '@microsoft.azure/autorest.modeler' (2.3.55- 
>2.3.55)
FATAL: swagger-document/loader - FAILED
```

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/docs/autorest-versioning.md

Comment: https://developers.refinitiv.com/article/how-use-autorest-rdp

Comment: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/50079755-missing-openapi-operationid-specification-field-causes-autorest-to-terminate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412998/swashbuckle-set-manualy-operationid-mutiple-opertaions-with-same-verb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842357/autorest-gives-different-error-generating-from-local-swagger-json-than-remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the --v3 switch

```
autorest --v3 --input-file=https://myapplication/mydocs/v1/swagger.json --output-folder=generated --csharp --namespace=MyNameSpace
```

Comment: I am really baffled that a newer version is hidden behind some magical flag. I hope they make V3 the default at some point.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen your hopes are satisfied, here is the update as of 06/14/21: "⚠️ We have updated the default generator used by autorest --csharp to the new version V3 [...]" (https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp)